#  map not  showing traffic info

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I have an android application with google map and I am showing some information and points in this map. I used some piece of code to show google traffic information:

there is:

```
mapView.setTraffic(true);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Problem is that the traffic information is not visible on my position (Slovakia), but in others countries like(Slovakia was added with google to traffic information ...)
what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

same does happen in map js api in web browser. All other close countries are showing traffic Slovakia is not despite the fact that maps.google.com does show traffic also for Slovakia... 
Funny.

Comment: google maps works fine now, but android maps or iPhone maps don't work ... it is crazy